# Enviar usuário para um app de email

Tags: java, android, email

Eu quero enviar o usuário para um aplicativo de email, porém só quero setar o destinatário, o resto o próprio usuário vai preencher no aplicativo que ele escolheu e depois enviar

Tem como?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar esse código abaixo:

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String\[\]{  "destinatario@gmail.com"});           
emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");

try {
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Escolha o App desejado..."));
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Não há programas de email instalados.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Dessa forma o usuário poderá escolher o APP desejado para o envio do email, e já abrirá o APP com o endereço de email preenchido

Comment: Funciono como eu queria, valeu

Comment: Poderia me ajudar em mais uma coisa? O código funciona perfeitamente mao seria possível ter uma opcao que defina um aplicativo padrão?